# Sending Mail via Node Mailer is not working getting Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Here is my code for sending mail via nodemailer

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'vaishups12@gmail.com',
    pass: '*****'
  }
});               

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'vaishups12@gmail.com',
  to: 'vaishushinde312@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending mail via NodeMailer',
  text: `Hello... It is a practice mail !!!`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log("error");
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

I have enable the gmail access. As I'm trying to run this code, I was getting error as below

```
    $ node nodemailer.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fc/NODE_COURSE/new_node_programs/nodemailer.js:29:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you installed the module? `npm install`

Comment: Yes.. I am getting "permission denied" error

Comment: Try running it with `sudo`

Comment: yah, installed modules, but again getting above error